# Is there a Google Dataflow MongoDB Source/Sink?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I know Google Dataflow only officially supports as I/O for a Dataflow a file in Google Cloud Storage, BigQuery, Avro files or Pub/Sub out of the box.

But as it has an [API for Custom Source and Sink](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io) I was wondering, is there some Pipeline I/O implementation for MongoDB?

Right now I will have to either migrate my data to BigQuery or write the whole Pipeline I/O implementation before even being able to know if Google Dataflow is a viable solution to my current problems.

I tried googling and looking at the [current SDK issues](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20mongodb) and didn't see anything related. I even started to wonder if I missed something very basic from Google Dataflow concept and docs that completely invalidades this initial idea to use MongoDB as a data source.

Comment: I updated my answer. A MongoDB connector is now available.

Comment: @jkff good to know, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently a MongoDB connector was added to [Apache Beam (incubating)](http://beam.apache.org). Please see [MongoDBIO](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/mongodb/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mongodb/MongoDbIO.java).